# Problem with Active Window on Selenium Grid 4 running parallel scripts

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Im using C# + MSTest V2 + Selenium 4 and running multiple scripts in parallel on Azure Pipeline (I could have 25 scripts at the same time), I have 10 nodes where each node allows 10 Chrome Sessions.

Mi problem is when a single node try to run more than 1 session, I could inspect and see the sessions running and is like just the active Chrome Instance move on, the rest get stucked until it takes the focus.

I tried setting single session on each node, but then I run out of available sessions and I get an error trying to initialize a Chrome session